# How can I pass the currently focused element name through a CommandParameter in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, commandparameter

In my WPF MVVM application I want to be able to undo changes to individual TextBox elements using the Esc key. I've set up a command for this and I want to trigger it through XAML thus:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding EscKeyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FocusManager.FocusedElement}"  Gesture="ESC" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The idea is that the CommandParameter passes the ElementName  of the currently focussed TextBox (if indeed that's what's in focus) and the appropriate undo can then be handled within the ViewModel. I've tried a number of options for the CommandParameter including the one above but they all return null. So,

**Question**

How can I pass the currently focused element name through a CommandParameter?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question I've specifically posed but I've just realised that I can determine the focused element name in the command using Keyboard.FocusedElement. No need therefore to pass any CommandParameter.

Comment: As a user, I'd be surprised if ESC was "Undo". Ctrl-Z is "undo".

Comment: Indeed, but I have surprising users ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad that you have already noticed `KeyBoard.FocusedElment`. But there still an answer for the question. Since `FocusManager.FocusedElement` is an attached property, the right way to bind it should be:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding (FocusManager.FocusedElement), ElementName='name of the window'}"
```

Comment: Great this works perfectly as does the @AselaLiyanage answer. So which should I go for? Staying with the MVVM / decoupling mindset I think this one because the Command then just takes action on "an element from somewhere". Using Keyboard.FocusedElement within the command feels more like a conversation with the UI. Probably splitting hairs here mind you. Thanks to both for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

`FocusManager` gives the element with the logical focus. To use `FocusManager.FocusedElement` the scope needs to provided, in this case the window `(this)`

```
IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

But In your case since it is a text box that you need the focus of use `Keyboard.FocusedElement`.

In the view model when you execute `EscKeyCommand` get the element that has the keyboard focus with the following syntax and clear the text.

```
UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
```