# How to get name of element with focus in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm building a Mahjong game that has more buttons than Sgt. Pepper's band. The movement of the tile is simulated by showing the background of the button (tile) in question.  I'd like to leverage the use of `x:Name="button"`and have only one click event, than 200 but the problem is in getting the name of the focused button.  I can get the element with the focus but can not access the name property, if I could I would save a lot of inelegant drudgery. Here's what I'd like to do;

```
Private Sub b15_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles b15.Click
    Dim brush As Brush
    Dim vButton As Button
    Dim InputElement As IInputElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement
    vButton.Name = InputElement.name  '!! here's the problem !! 
    If vTog = 0 Then 'background brush transferred from
        brush = vButton.Background
        vButton.Background = Nothing
        vTog = 1
    Else 'background brush transferred to
        vButton.Background = brush
        vTog = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Maybe I've missed an easy way to get the button's name so I can use it directly in the code behind.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this article help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581780/how-can-i-pass-the-currently-focused-element-name-through-a-commandparameter-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend learning more about the basics of WPF.

As well as "regular" events WPF has routed events. See the signature of your click handler? Notice Routedeventargs rather than eventargs?

That click event is a routed event.

Routed events bubble ( up the visual tree ) and or tunnel (down the visual tree).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview

Because of this mechanism, you can handle a click event of buttons at a container further up the visual tree. That could be a grid, stackpanel or window.

In the handler, cast the originalsource of the event to button and that will have a name property.

I do c# but there is very little code to this and if you have trouble following it then you could put it through an online code converter.

Markup:

```
        Title="MainWindow" 
        ButtonBase.Click="Window_Button_Click"
        >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="b1"     Content="b1"/>
        <Button Name="b2" Content="b2"/>
        <Button Name="b3" Content="b3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Handler in code behind:

```
    private void Window_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        Button btn = e.OriginalSource as Button;
        if(btn!=null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(btn.Name ?? "No Name for this button"); 
        }
    }
```

If I spin that up with an f5, I see the name of each button clicked output to my output window when I click on them.

As an aside.

I'm not clear what the player clicks and what that does.

Maybe this could work in a generic way and the datacontext of each button would be a viewmodel holding x,y location or some such.

Comment: that is exactly what I was trying to do, it works perfectly.  To answer your aside question, when a player clicks on a button (tile) it removes the background from that button, then when he clicks again on an unused tile, the background is placed there, so on a game level, it moves a tile from one position to another.  Thanks for your help!